# Ace editor, how to remove all keyBindings but one?

Tags: javascript, key-bindings, ace-editor

I recently had a textarea on my jsp page

For it, I had my own shortcuts on the keyboard

Then, I implemented the ace editor, and all my old keybindings didn't work then

Then i searched for a while, and found this code:

```
    //I did this before, to add the ace editor
    var editor = ace.edit("fileInfo");
    var JavaScriptMode = ace.require("ace/mode/javascript").Mode;
    editor.session.setMode(new JavaScriptMode()); 

   //Then I found this for the keyBindings
    delete editor.keyBinding;
```

The last line, disables all the keyBindings from the ace editor, and my own keyBindings came to work...
All worked fine, but then, I searched a lot about the ace editor, and found one interesting option, and thet is the one keyBinding, that I love to use, and that is the DELETE ROW keybinding Ctrl + D

and I want now to get it back, but only it, not the others, and ofc my old keyBindings should also work...

The code for my old keyBindings looks like this:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
            // Ctrl + S = SAVE
            if (e.keyCode == 83 && (navigator.platform.match("Mac") ? e.metaKey : e.ctrlKey))      {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                if($scope.mode!='BROWSE')
                {
                    $('#saveBtn').trigger("click");
                }
            }
}, false);
```

Can u help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`delete editor.keyBinding;` is not a good solution, it will produce error messages in console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ctrl-d' of undefined
>       at CommandManager.handleKeyboard (ace.js:10830)
>       at KeyBinding.$callKeyboardHandlers (ace.js:4081)
>       at KeyBinding.onCommandKey (ace.js:4113)
>       at Editor.onCommandKey (ace.js:12424)
>       at normalizeCommandKeys (ace.js:1648)
>       at HTMLTextAreaElement. (ace.js:1667)

## Option 1: delete all bindings and redefine the one we need.

```
//safely delete all bindings
editor.keyBinding.$defaultHandler.commandKeyBinding = {}
//bind the wanted command
editor.commands.addCommand({
    name: "removeline",
    bindKey: { win: "Ctrl-D", mac: "Command-D" },
    exec: function(editor) { editor.removeLines(); },
    scrollIntoView: "cursor",
    multiSelectAction: "forEachLine"
});
```

now that you have the command defined, you can call it from your own code if needed:

```
editor.execCommand("removeline")
```

### Option 2: actually looping through the bindings.

using `for (key in obj)` to loop through the key bindings and deleting keys that are not equal to `ctrl-d` and `command-d`:

```
for (key in editor.keyBinding.$defaultHandler.commandKeyBinding) {
    if (key !== "ctrl-d" && key !== "command-d")
        delete editor.keyBinding.$defaultHandler.commandKeyBinding[key]
}
```

Comment: I just tried this:   if (e.keyCode == 68 && (navigator.platform.match("Mac") ?e.metaKey : e.ctrlKey)) { 
       e.preventDefault();
       e.stopPropagation(); 
       if($scope.mode=='BROWSE' && $scope.selectedScript!=null) 
       {
        execCommand("removeline");
       } 
      }, and it didnt work, it tells me execCommand is not defined is not a function....

Comment: I tried the command in console here (https://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html) and they seem to work well, I added another option, try it please. also tested

Comment: also the correct way to call the command is `editor.execCommand("removeline")`

Comment: I suggest you try `editor.execCommand("removeline")` in console first, it should execute. than worry about binding it.

Comment: the option 2 is better for me, thx man.....now i just have to find out how to prevent my browser to do the bookmark stuf.....mby u can help me there too?

Comment: You're welcome, mark the solution and vote up. I'll try to look into the other issue once I'm back at the office. Meanwhile please provide more info or open another question and link it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42412824/how-to-prevent-the-browser-to-override-my-keybindings-of-ace-editor

Comment: improved the answer, please have a look

Comment: thx man, sry for my late reply, the option one was indeed better