# How to prevent the browser to override my keyBindings of ace editor?

Tags: javascript, key-bindings

This question came up after i implemented the ace editor...

here is the link for that:

[Ace editor, how to remove all keyBindings but one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42410689/ace-editor-how-to-remove-all-keybindings-but-one#42411151)

I have the ace editor, and thx to the for loop:

```
for (key in editor.keyBinding.$defaultHandler.commandKeyBinding) {
            if (key !== "ctrl-d")
                delete editor.keyBinding.$defaultHandler.commandKeyBinding[key];
        }
```

I have my own keyBindings, and the ace editor has its own, witch i deleted, all but one, and that one is the CTRL+D to remove a line...

but, my browser has already the ctrl-d stuff on the bookmark, and i need now to prevent that, any ideas?

Comment: hello again, I'm not able to reproduce the issue,ace editor seems to prevent default action (adding to fav) by default.

and the solution you're using doesn't affect ace-editor native function so it should work as it is.

Comment: I had just the same problem, but resolved by returning "true" or nothing (no "return" keyword) in my callback. When I return "false", event seems no prevented…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested in ace-editor and default function seem to block default keyboard shortcuts on its own. but for the sake of answering your question, you can use an event listener for `ctrl + d` and `command + d` than use `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()`... now to how would you use it with ace-editor:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.key.toLowerCase() == "d" && (navigator.platform.match("Mac") ? e.metaKey : e.ctrlKey)) {
        editor.execCommand("removeline");
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
}, false);
```

- notice how I used `e.key.toLowerCase() == "d"` instead of `e.keyCode == 68` ... this is because [KeyboardEvent.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) is now marked as **deprecated** so I used [KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead. the `.toLowerCase()` is used so the shortcut work even when Caps Lock is toggled.
- one downside of using `e.key` instead of `e.keyCode` is that `e.key` will only work with English/Latin keyboard input so the key must be literally "d" while `e.keyCode` will work with other languages input like Arabic for example (ctrl + ي)... so you decide which one to use.

if you already removed the default binding/command for the wanted command [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42410689/ace-editor-how-to-remove-all-keybindings-but-one) you can add it without its key binding like this:

```
editor.commands.addCommand({
    name: "removeline",
    exec: function(editor) { editor.removeLines(); },
    scrollIntoView: "cursor",
    multiSelectAction: "forEachLine"
});
```

- it's neccsarry for this command to exist so `editor.execCommand("removeline")` will work